# Android Socket.io Background Service

Tags: android, socket.io, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

I have a socket.io library. It's a websocket library on JavaScript. 
I want to keep alive 7/24 the service but the android OREO have background service limits. How can i solve it ? I want to check the client is alive or not. The whatsapp, facebook and skype how do that? I want to ping the every 3 seconds to my server. But i want to keep alive the sockets connections.

Comment: You can use ForgroundService for that

Answer (score 1):

Try Evernote job library, Its compatibility for all android version

[Link](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)